# curl listing on autoscout24.de

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I'm trying to make a script that will login and then post a car automatically on autoscout24.de. I have passed the login with php using curl, but I'm having some problems when I try to post a car: the form that they use is by ajax

```
(h = function () {
                $("#OfferData").valid() ? ($("#LoginButton").unbind("click"),
$(document).unbind("saveOffer"), o.saveOpen(),
IdentityServiceIntegration ? 
isAuthenticatedUser && !isBasicUser ? g("/classified/save") : $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: !1,
                    url: "/classified/updatetemporary",
                    data: $("#OfferData").serialize(),
                    success: M
                }) : g("/classified/save")) : j.focusFirstInvalidField()
            },
            N = function (a, b) {
                u && b && g("/classified/edit")
            },
            g = function (a) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: !1,
                    url: a,
                    data: $("#OfferData").serialize(),
                    success: e.offerSaved
                })
            },)
```

The rest of the JavaScript can be found here: http://goo.gl/MDB6ZO

I couldn't find the actual action link of the form to make the curl request.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debug tool called *inspector* in your browser (chrome for example), checkout network tab. It shows all network queries

Comment: thanks I did managed to see how it works now, but I still got a problem. I see that the website is making a request and saves the data step by step...is there a way that I can send all the data with curl at once?

Comment: Sure, curl is able to send all kinds of requests, you should look at the request in debugger and make the same request with curl. Also pay attention to cookies